# django delete object from post (bootstrap)

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a way to delete objects from frontend using a form and Bootstrap. The alert box is closing but upon page refresh the object is still present and no deletion is made in database.

What's the proper way of implementing this? Please help!

forms.py

```
 class DeleteAlertForm(forms.ModelForm):
      def is_valid(self):
        form = super(DeleteAlertForm, self).is_valid()
        for f, error in self.errors.iteritems():
          if f != '__all__':
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': strip_tags(error)})
        return form

  class Meta:  
    model = Alert
    fields = []
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def delete(request, alert_id):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = DeleteAlertForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): # checks CSRF
      a_id = request.POST.get('alert_id', False)
      alert = New.objects.get(pk=a_id)
      alert.delete()
      return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
  else:
    return redirect('/')
  return redirect('/')
```

template.html

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-block">
<form action="/delete/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" value="{{alert.id}}" name="alert_id">
<button type="submit" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
</form>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete$', login_required(DeleteView.as_view(
model=Alert,
success_url='/',
template_name='portal/alert_confirm_delete.html',))),
```

Comment: Please post your `urls.py` or the coe where you define the template to be used for rendering. Additionally show the code-part that is used to assigned to the `alert.id` variable

Comment: I've updated the post with urls.py, taken from @MatthewDaly's example..

Comment: Do the posts get deleted now? I would have assumed the error to be in an empty queryset, which you would not have noticed due to the instant redirection via `HttpResponseRedirect`and the missing exception-output. PS: Don't feel obliged to select SO answers that were well meaning but didn't fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use Django with your own delete-template using bootstrap.
As the user-interface and redirection are described to be as intended, the **error** appears that you have set the wrong model: `New` in your `delete` action, which became clear after you updated/posted your revised `urls.py`. The model on which to run delete should be `Alert`

In your `delete` action a queryset comprised of an entry corresponding to the primary key of `New`-entries is selected as being equal to `alert_id`.

```
  alert = New.objects.get(pk=a_id)
```

The intended Model should likely be `Alert`

To fetch entries from your Model `New` using `Alert` entries, set a `ForeignKey` relationship in the Model `New` as follows. For instance:

```
class New(models.Model):
  alert = models.ForeignKey(Alert, verbose_name=_("Alert posts"))
  ....
```

Django's Object-Relational-Mapper will thus create a datebase field called `alert_id` with the proper relationship CONSTRAINTS and ForeignKeys.

Don't forget to run [syndb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) on the shell afterwards. e.g. using `manage.py syndb`

Django probably threw a `DoesNotExist` exception similar to the one shown:

```
In [2]: appname.models.New.objects.get(pk=-1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DoesNotExist                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 lead.models.Lead.objects.get(pk=-1)

/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    129
    130     def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 131         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
    132
    133     def get_or_create(self, **kwargs):
....
DoesNotExist: Lead matching query does not exist.
```

Whilst Django is setup by default to show you exceptions if DEBUG is turned on in `settings.py`, you instantly redirected within your code and did not handle/output exceptions.

Exceptions should still be logged by default, and written to a log file whose location depends on the server you are running.

You can set up log-handling in your project's `settings.py` using the variable `LOGGING = {...}`. See the [Django manual on logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django-s-default-logging-configuration).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a [DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView)?

He're's how you might implement a URL for this:

```
    url(r'^mymodel/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', login_required(DeleteView.as_view(
        model=MyModel,
        success_url="/mymodel/deleted/",
        template_name="myapp/mymodel_confirm_delete.html",
    ))),
```

You would need to implement something similar for each model you want to be able to delete. However, the only other code you would need in your `urls.py` is importing DeleteView. You could use the same template and success URL for all of your models, however.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know of if. Found this page a bit more straight forward than the examples from the official documentation. http://georgebrock.github.io/talks/intro-to-class-based-generic-views/

Comment: @JoarSvensson Generic views are one of Django's killer features. I would always use a generic view unless there was a good reason not to. They cover the vast majority of use cases, and are easy to extend, and it's unbelievable how much time they can save you.

Comment: I find it a bit hard to use these classes when it comes to templates.. I don't want a new page for every form.. how is it possible to implement it the way I started with?

Comment: @JoarSvensson Don't worry about it at this point. If what you have now is fine, go with it, but bear in mind that generic views should usually be your first choice for implementing any kind of view.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Daly, but Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: @JoarSvensson You can still, at least in principle, use a DeleteView for this. All you need to do is set up something in your urls.py to map a specific route to a DeleteView for an object, then to delete something you just submit an HTTP POST request for it. Eg, if you were deleting blog posts, the URL might be post/1/delete, and sending an HTTP POST request to that would delete the post. I've amended my answer to make this a bit clearer